# Running a Website on Another Domain from Our Server

Tags: resin

we are going to develop an asp.net application on our windows server that we want to run on another companies domain name, http://notourdomain.com.  The server which the domain is currently on is Resin and their language is Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment

What is the best way to make this happen?

We would need our application to run on "notourdomain.com/app/"

so if on our server it was "ourserver.com/app/dir1/page/" or "ourserver.com/dir1/page/"

on their domain it would show as "notourdomain.com/app/dir/page/"

They suggested to do the URL redirecting using their load balancing so the content appears to be serving up from "notourdomain.com"

Do you have any other suggestions or specifics on how this would be set up?  Positives, negatives, comments, etc?

Thank you for any information you can give on this.

Comment: To clarify, the entire notourdomain.com website will be hosted on their server, except for /app/* which goes to your server?

Comment: Is their Resin server running in front, responding to every single HTTP request, even for static content, or do they have a HTTP server in front of Resin, such as Apache?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create a subdomain, this might be the option that would have minor chance of url conflicting between the two apps.

So it will be something like this:

http://yourappname.notourdomain.com

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Unfortunately, we thought the same, but it's not an option b/c our client insists it be on the same domain for seo purposes.  Can you think of any other ways around it?  For instance, wordpress uses .com/blog/ or whatever directory you give it.  Just trying to brainstorm.  Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

If you're cool with a redirect to `http://ourserver.com/app/*` (rather than transparently using the `notourdomain.com` domain) and the load balancer supports it, then by all means have their load balancer redirect to your website.

However, if you don't want the hostname to change at all due to a redirect, read on:

First, if their load balancer can proxy (not redirect) requests to your server, then that would be a good method.

Are they running a HTTP server in front of Resin (e.g., Apache, nginx)?  If so, many popular HTTP servers support proxying.  The HTTP server can be configured to proxy all requests for `/app/*` to `http://ourserver.com/app/*`.

If they're not running a HTTP server, and Resin is the front line server responding to every HTTP request, then I'm not familiar with Resin so I can't give specifics.  But you should look into whether Resin can be configured to proxy certain requests.  If not, then perhaps you can create servlet that runs in Resin and responds to `/app/*` requests.  This servlet's only job is to act as a proxy, connecting to `ourserver.com` to retrieve the appropriate page and pass the result on to the client.  This is the least ideal solution.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that's what I was looking for.  So ideally they would configure their server to proxy all requests for /app/* to our server.  So if I understand correctly, it doesn't matter if we have app/what-ever/wewant.aspx even if they're running java it will show on their domain.  I guess they would use htaccess for this??  Do you have any idea what the code would be?  Thank you for the time you've given and your info...

Comment: The first step would be to ask them what their proxying capabilities are, as outlined in my answer.  You can configure proxying in .htaccess if they have an Apache web server, for instance.  Exactly how it's configured depends on what they're running.